# Handling TSX null value

Tags: typescript

This syntax

```
<input
  type="file"
  id="input"
  onChange={let a = 1; e => this.setFilePath(e.target.files[0])}
/>
```

generates a warning

```
Object is possibly 'null'.
```

How can I handle this without resorting to // @ts-ignore:?

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly not much more elegant that // @ts-ignore, but if `e.target.files[0]` will never be null, you could use a [not-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (exclamation point).

```
<input
            type="file"
            id="input"
            onChange={let a = 1; e => this.setFilePath(e.target.files[0]!)}
          />
```